# Mac Terminal Open Command - Save PID of Opened Application?

Tags: xcode, macos, unix

I'd like to open an xcode workspace in terminal, wait some time, then close that workspace (xcode has some hidden magic it does on projects that makes this necessary in an automated build process).

So something like-

```
pid=`open proj.xcworkspace`
sleep 30
kill $pid
```

Because multiple xcode projects may be running in the same time. I can't simply kill xcode, just the process I started.

How can I get the PID of an application I open in terminal?

Comment: `open` does not necessarily launch a new process. If the app is already running, the existing process is just sent an event telling it to open the document. (You can override that with the `-n` option, but not all applications cope well with multiple instances. I would not expect Xcode to cope well.) It looks like Xcode's AppleScript interface supports what you're trying to do. There's even a related example in the docs for the `workspace document` class.

Comment: I need to do this too.

Answer (score -1):

You can catch the current `Process ID` with `$$`.

Or you can search for `Process IDs` with `ps -C PROGRAMM_NAME -o pid=`.

```
suleiman@antec:~$ ps -C icedove -o pid=
 887

suleiman@antec:~$ ps -C vlc -o pid=
29405
```

---

**Addition...**

Here is a working example of what I mean ...

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while [ "$i" -le 10 ]
do
    example.sh &
    Pid[$i]=$(ps -C "example.sh" -o "pid=")
    Pid[$i]=$(echo "${Pid[$i]}" | tail -n 1)
    #echo "${Pid[$i]}"
    i=$(($i +1))
done

for PID in "${Pid[@]}"
do
    kill "$PID"
done
exit 0
```

Comment: I don't need the current process id. I only want to kill one instance of the many possible instances. I don't think this helps.

Comment: you may not need `$$` but the other example should suit your needs.

Comment: Still not sure it does. I have 2 instances of xcode running. I open another instance of xcode. How do I close that instance I just opened without closing the other instances?

Comment: Every process has its own ID... you need to get that ID via `ps` or `top` and put it into a variable or file. The `kill` command you know already. Just test it. You will need to know the name of the process when you started. Thats all.

Comment: you aren't telling me anything I don't already know. obviously I am trying to do this programatically. using ps or top will not single out the process I just opened if I have multiple processes for the same application running.

Comment: It works for me and I updated my post to show you how.

Comment: Dude. The fact that you do it in a loop should *hint* that you aren't understanding what I mean. I don't want to kill all `example.sh`. I just want to kill the one `example.sh` I just opened in a sea of existing `example.sh` processes. Also I don't believe `ps -C "example.sh" -o "pid="` works on mac.

Comment: So yeah. It works for you. But it solves a problem I don't have. Strawman solution.